# How to use Repeater inside RadioButtonList to repeat ListItem of RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

First, Can repeater with in a repeater be used?
If yes than how I can use nested repeater in following scenario.

```
<div class="row">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rp_Question" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <p class="_100">
                <h2 id="h4_Question" runat="server"><%# Eval("question_text") %></h2>
            </p>
            <p class="left">
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rb_Question" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Option1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Option2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Option3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Option4" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </p>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater
```

Repeater Binding

```
rp_Question.DataSource = _question.GetAll();
rp_Question.DataBind();
```

The options of each question are saved in database, minimum option could be 3 and maximum could be 6. How can I use an other repeater inside **rp_Question** to repeat options of each question.
I want to show out put like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on the answer KateCute gave, you can use the `ItemDataBound` event for that.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rp_Question" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rp_Question_ItemDataBound">
```

And then in code behind.

```
protected void rp_Question_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    //find the radiobuttonlist with findcontrol and cast back to it's original type
    RadioButtonList rb_Question = e.Item.FindControl("rb_Question") as RadioButtonList;

    //get the current datarow
    DataRowView row = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;

    //get the id from the datarow object
    string questionID = row["question_id"].ToString();

    //get the answers from the db with questionID and bind them as listitems just like in the loop below

    //just a loop to add some listitems for demo
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        rb_Question.Items.Insert(i, new ListItem("Option " + i.ToString(), i.ToString(), true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't use repeater inside `asp:RadioButtonList`. It allows only `ListItem` inside. You will get an error, that repeater is a not known element. But you can bind `asp:RadioButtonList` in code behind.

Comment: can you please share some code to bind 'asp:RadioButtonList' placed inside repeater?